# project tango- cpp_mesh_builder_exampledlopen("/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed:

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm try to run the **cpp_mesh_builder_example** on my project tango tablet,my pc environment is win10 ,android studio 2.2.the demo I run  is  from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c) ,and I succeed to run some basic examples like **hello_depth_perception** and so on.But when I run that demo ,the demo shutdown right after it opened,and the android monitor shows errors like this:

```
01-03 15:08:54.700 14086-14086/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder E/art: dlopen("/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so" not found
01-03 15:08:54.731 14086-14086/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder E/art: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder-2/libcpp_mesh_builder_example.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libtango_3d_reconstruction.so" needed by "libcpp_mesh_builder_example.so"; caused by cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "libtango_3d_reconstruction.so"...
01-03 15:08:54.733 14086-14086/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder, PID: 14086
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder.MeshBuilderActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder.MeshBuilderActivity
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder.MeshBuilderActivity
                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libtango_3d_reconstruction.so" needed by "libcpp_mesh_builder_example.so"; caused by cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "libtango_3d_reconstruction.so"...
                                                                                               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
                                                                                               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                                               at com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder.TangoJNINative.(TangoJNINative.java:36)
                                                                                               at com.projecttango.examples.cpp.meshbuilder.MeshBuilderActivity.(MeshBuilderActivity.java:70)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559) 
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
```

who can tell me what happened? I didn't change the source code

Comment: The first line of the error tells you exactly what happened. `library "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so" not found`

Comment: thanks for your answer,  but I find libtango_client_api.so under the tango-examples-c\tango_client_api\lib\arm64-v8a, and my android.mk includes` $(call import-module,tango_client_api)`  . I am sorry that I am new to Android and JNI ,but how to solve this problem?